# EDGE и IE неправильно отображают стили

Tags: css, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность, microsoft-edge

Помогите, edge и ie как то неправильно отображает мои стили для чекбоксов

```css
    .item_opt[type="checkbox"], #item_opt_4[type="checkbox"] {
              width: 50px;
              height: 24px;
              vertical-align: -6.5px;
              -webkit-appearance: none;
              -moz-appearance: none;
              outline: none;
              border-radius: 19px;
              box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0, .2);
              transition: 0.2s;
              position: relative;
              cursor: pointer
            }

            .item_opt[type="checkbox"]:active, #item_opt[type="checkbox"]:focus, #item_opt[type="checkbox"]:focus,#item_opt[type="checkbox"]:active {
              outline: none;
            }
            .item_opt[type="checkbox"]::-moz-focus-inner {
              border: 0;
            }

            .item_opt:checked[type="checkbox"], #item_opt_4:checked[type="checkbox"] {
              background: #7F2929;
            }
            .item_opt:disabled[type="checkbox"], #item_opt_4:disabled[type="checkbox"] {
              background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
            }
            .item_opt[type="checkbox"]::before, #item_opt_4[type="checkbox"]::before {
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              width: 20px;
              height: 20px;
              border-radius: 50%;
              top: 1.6px;
              left: 2px;
              background: #FFFFFF;
              transform: scale(1.1);
              box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
              transition: 0.2s;
            }
            .item_opt:checked[type="checkbox"]::before, #item_opt_4:checked[type="checkbox"]::before {
              left: 28px;
            }
```

```html
 <input class="item_opt" type="checkbox" id="item_opt_sim"  > Исключать похожие<i  data-toggle="tooltip" style="cursor:pointer" data-placement="top" title="Похожие символы B8 G6 I1l| 0OQD S5 Z2">
```

хром
[image: chrome]

edge
[image: edge]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не работает, так как к `input` применять `::after` и `::before` не корректно.

`::before` и `::after` добавляет контент к содержимому элемента, а у `input` как такового содержимого нет. Вам следует обернуть инпут в парный тег и к нему уже применять псевдоэлементы.

Comment: Тогда почему у хрома все работает?

Comment: Потому что хром нарушает спецификацию, согласно которой нельзя добавлять псевдоелементы тегам без закрывающегося тега. А такие браузеры, например, как edge и ie - нет.

Comment: А тут [на enSO говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831620/is-the-before-pseudo-element-allowed-on-an-inputtype-checkbox), что в спецификации ничего конкретного про это не сказано